# How to How to take one element from list, compare it with another from the same series?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, series

I need to print from the series ('fluorescence') only the elements that are above a certain numerical threshold.

How can I take one element, compare it with another from the same series, and in case the condition is not met, simply move on in the series?

```
#for i in range(len(fluorescence)):
for i in fluorescence.iteritems():

   if i > 43: # (mean(fluorescence)-min(fluorescence)) == 43.
       print(i)
```

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'float'

This is the original dataframe:
[image]

What I would like to have is the following:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: [Include your minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of the example.  Your posted code fails to run.

Comment: Please don't post images, post the textual data instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iteritems` returns a tuple of (key, value).  You can't compare the entire tuple to a scalar.

```
if i[1] > 43:
```

should fix your problem.  See the other answer for a far better way to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

[filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) is what you need here.

```py
# Filter will filter an iterator if the function returns True
fluorescence = [94, 35, 12, 104]
result = list(filter(lambda x: x > 43, fluorescence))
print(result)
# [94, 104]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas tolist() will convert the series to a list which is easily iterable.

```
#an empty list to store the values
new=[]
for i in fluorescence.tolist():
if i > 43
new.append(i)
print(new)
#print statement not in the loop
```